# Script to count number of emails for multiple users

Tags: powershell, exchange-server

I am needing a little help with my script.  I have this working if I use just a single email address.  I need to add a list of 8 emails addresses for this to scan.  How would I modify this to send 1 email for all 8 users?

I have seen scripts that make a html file that displays everything in a nice table but those are ran against all users in exchange and I only needs this for a group of 8 users.

```
  Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.Exchange.Management.PowerShell.E2010

#Powershell blah blah blah
$nl = [Environment]::NewLine

#Mailbox to gather stats on
$mailboxs=$mailbox= 'user1@domain.com','user2@domain.com'


#Get todays
$startDate=Get-Date
$endDate=Get-Date

#Subtract 1 day from todays date (report ending day) and 1 day from todays date (report starting day)
$startDateFormatted=$startDate.AddDays(-1).ToShortDateString()
$endDateFormatted=$endDate.AddDays(-1).ToShortDateString()

foreach ($mailbox in $mailboxs)
{
# Sent e-mails
$sendCount = Get-TransportService | Get-MessageTrackingLog -Start "$startDateFormatted 00:00:00" -End "$endDateFormatted 23:59:59" -Sender $mailbox -resultsize unlimited | select-object -unique MessageId

# Received e-mails - This works but not on generic accounts
$receiveCount = Get-TransportService | Get-MessageTrackingLog -Start "$startDateFormatted 00:00:00" -End "$endDateFormatted 23:59:59" -Recipients $mailbox -resultsize unlimited | select-object -unique MessageId

$sendCountString = $sendCount.count
$receiveCountString = $receiveCount.count
}

$Output = 
$Mailbox | 
foreach {
$ResultHash = 
 @{
    Address = $_
    Sent    = $Sendcountstring
    Received = $Receivecountstring
   }

 New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property $ResultHash |
  Select Address,Sent,Received
  }

#Who to send the e-mail report to.
#Multiple e-mail addresses should be in this format "<email1@domain.com>, <email2@domain.com>"

$MailParams = @{
From = "ISSReports@domain.com"
To = "user3@domain.com"
subject = "Daily e-mail report for ISS for $startDateFormatted"
BodyAsHTML = $true
smtpServer = "mail.domain.com"
}

$header = 
@"
"Mailbox Stats
Report date range: $startDateFormatted 00:00:00 - $endDateFormatted 23:59:59 
"@

$body = $Output | ConvertTo-Html -As Table -Head $header | out-string

Send-MailMessage @MailParams -Body $body
```

Answer (score 0):

I put this together from your script and some pieces borrowed from a couple of my own.  For this kind of reporting, you only need to read through the logs once, and you can eliminate the need to de-dupe by messageid by only returning the Deliver events.  There will be one deliver event per email sent, containing both the sender and recipients.

```
#Mailboxs to gather stats on
$mailbox= 'user1@domain.com','user2@domain.com'

#Get todays date twice
$startDate=Get-Date
$endDate=Get-Date

#Hash tables for send and receive counts
$Sent = @{}
$Received = @{}

#Subtract 1 day from todays date (report ending day) and 1 days from todays date (report starting day)
$startDateFormatted=$startDate.AddDays(-1).ToShortDateString()
$endDateFormatted=$endDate.AddDays(-1).ToShortDateString()

$TransportServers = Get-ExchangeServer  |
 Where {$_.serverrole -match "hubtransport"} |
 Select -ExpandProperty Name

foreach ($TransportServer in $TransportServers)
{
  Get-MessageTrackingLog -Start "$startDateFormatted 00:00:00" -End "$endDateFormatted 23:59:59" -EventID Deliver -Server $TransportServer -ResultSize Unlimited |
   foreach {
    if ($mailbox -contains $_.sender )
      { $Sent[$_.Sender]++ }

    foreach ($Recipient in $_.Recipients)
     {
      if ($mailbox -contains $Recipient )
       { $Received[$Recipient]++ }
     }
   }
 }

$Output = 
$Mailbox | 
foreach {
 $ResultHash = 
 @{
    Address = $_
    Sent    = $Sent[$_]
    Received = $Received[$_]
   }

 New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property $ResultHash |
  Select Address,Sent,Received
}

#Who to send the e-mail report to.
#Multiple e-mail addresses should be in this format "<email1@domain.com>, <email2@domain.com>"

$MailParams = @{
From = "ISSReports@domain.com"
To = "user3@domain.com"
subject = "Weekly e-mail report for $mailbox for $startDateFormatted - $endDateFormatted"
BodyAsHTML = $true
smtpServer = "mail.domain.com"
}

$header = 
@"
"Mailbox Stats
Report date range: $startDateFormatted 00:00:00 - $endDateFormatted 23:59:59 
"@

$body = $Output | ConvertTo-Html -As Table -Head $header | out-string

Send-MailMessage @MailParams -Body $body
```

Comment: This is the error message I get running it now.     Send-MailMessage : Cannot convert 'System.Object[]' to the type 'System.String' required by parameter 'Body'. Specified 
method is not supported.
At C:\Users\dbeavin\Desktop\ISSTest.ps1:70 char:36
+ Send-MailMessage @MailParams -Body $body
+                                    ~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Send-MailMessage], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotConvertArgument,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SendMailMessage

Comment: I also had to add in Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.Exchange.Management.PowerShell.E2010 at the top since it needed to load the exchange cmdlets.  I am using this as a scheduled task so I needed to add it in.

Comment: Added  a pipe through out-string for $body.  That should fix the error.  You  don't necessarily have to load the snappin to have Exchange cmdlets.  I usually just connect to an Exchange server and use implicit remoting so I don't have to keep the Exchange management tools installed and updated on the server.

Comment: I was able to get it working but the email contains no data for send or received email.  I see the address populated with the two users but there is no other data.

Comment: I tested that much of it using a couple of known good addresses against my own tracking logs before I posted that.  Are these the primary smtp addresses of the mailboxes?

Comment: Yes these are the primary smtp address of the mailbox.  Essentially they want metrics for our internal sales department so I will be listing all of their email address at the top.  I populated my own to just see if anything would send and I get no data for sent or received messages.  I am on exchange 2013 if that makes a difference.  Not sure what version you tested on.

Comment: Are you testing with just one address?

Comment: I tested with 2, 1, and 3.  Nothing with any of them.

Comment: Don't know what to tell you then.  I can see where it would have a problem with a single address, since it's using -contains and expecting an array.  I'm not at work now, so I can't re-test until tomorrow, but as I said earlier I was getting results out of it on my own systems before I posted it.

Comment: I'll keep digging and see if I am missing something.

Comment: I didn't test the email bits, but there should be addresses and counts in the $sent and $received hash tables, and objects in $output.

Comment: I just need them to display a total number of sent and received messages.  Will this give more information than that for each user?  This is going to a manager that is just using it for metrics so the less information the better for them as far as extra data in the email.

Comment: It's just sent and received counts.  It should increment the hash table entry  for a given address in $sent once for each time the address appears as a sender, and increment the address in $received once for each time the address appears as a recipient.

Comment: I was able to get this partially working by adding some of code in with yours.  I can now only get it to display the information for the last mailbox I have listed.  I'll post what I did below.

Comment: I just modified my original post to show what I am using now.

Answer (score 0):

For these 8 mailboxes you need a count of messages sent by that mailbox?  This calls for 3 advanced functions:

1. count the mail
2. create a report
3. send the report

So, I see it like this (mostly pseudo-code):

```
Function Count-SentFromMbx { 

#paramter $mailbox
    #parameter $startdate
    #parameter $enddate
    # function counts sent mail per your working single user script
    #    or better yet, per mjolinor's script leveraging `-contains`
    # build custom object with mailbox and count as properties
    #    or better yet, enough information to build a digest.
    # return object/collection
} 

# Create a function to format the results email

# Create a function to send the results email

# Define collection of mailboxes
$mailboxes = "blah@blah.com","blah2@blah.com",etc.

# define or get the dates
$startdate = whatever
$enddate = whatever

# initialize array for results
$results = @{}

# set other variables for storage of the report
# and for recipient list
# and anything else needed 'globally'

# Pull data from the logs: 
    $results += Count-SentFromMbx -mailbox $mailbox -startdate $startdate -enddate $enddate

# if you end up with a collection of collections, you may need to change to 
#    $results = ... and add a line like `$results | $reportData += $_`

# build report using report function

# send report using send function
```

The main idea I am suggesting is to use advanced functions (`Get-Help about_advanced_functions`) for each modular task involved in the process.  Then you can leverage the power of objects to make gathering the data easy.  You can tailor your reports for your audience by tweaking the reports function.

Having your function return an object, try `$results | ConvertTo-Html`.  Bare minimum, if you have to build your own report, the collection of objects, $results, gives you an organized data source, easily passed through a foreach loop.  Using objects you could even expand the collection to return message digests instead of just the number of messages sent.  Instead of counting messages, create a custom object with subject, recipient and the sender.  (Easy way to create object is to pipe objects to select with a customized property list).  Return that collection and add it to the results collection.  Then reporting could include message digests AND totals.  The ability of objects to carry information gives you great flexibility.

One of the key things that mjolinor did was to put your 8 addresses in a collection.  When looping through, you can compare `if ($collection -contains $suspect) { do stuff}`.  This executes the block if the $suspect is in the $collection.  This allows you to loop through the logs once.